# Bug in current version of EasyChair?

Tags: easychair

We are currently using EasyChair for putting a conference program together.
When we use the feature

> Administration -> Other utilities -> List of accepted papers

we would expect to get a list of the accepted papers.

But instead, EasyChair shows us a beautiful html-page that contains a list of all **rejected** papers.
The first few lines on this page are:

> The list of accepted papers is shown below. You can also download the list as an HTML file to use in your conference Web pages. Note that if you to want to download the list both with and without abstracts, you will have to download it twice.

This clearly is a bug, and it was not around twelve months ago, when we used EasyChair for another meeting.

**Question: Is there a known work-around for this bug?**